# xml file does not download to heroku folder

Tags: php, heroku, codeigniter-3

I have a simple function that gets a "Blob" file from the database and tries to download it to heroku "collections" folder. It is working in my local computer where it takes the blob file and downloads it to my local directory but the same method does not work in Heroku.

```
 public function downloadCollectionFiles(){
        $this->load->helper('file');           
        $root  = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
        $root .= '/third_party/collections/';
        $this->load->model('invoice_page');

        $collectionData = $this->invoice_page->getCollectionTable();

        foreach($collectionData as $data){
            $invoiceName = 'xinvoices_xml'.'_'.date("Y-m-d").'_'.rand();  
            $paymentName ='updates_xml'.'_'.date("Y-m-d").'_'.rand();  
            if($data->invoice_xml){
                file_put_contents($root.$invoiceName.'.xml', $data->invoice_xml ); 
            }
            if($data->payment_xml){
                file_put_contents($root.$paymentName.'.xml', $data->payment_xml ); 
            }
           return true;    
    }
```

I have tried crazy amount of method, but it just does not download the file on a heroku folder called "collections"
The mysql stores this string as blob.

Comment: Which part does not work in production? Are you getting data from the database? Are you allowed to put files on disk?

Comment: @NicoHaase I can see that there is a string in the variable, and also the file put shows that it did not fail, but when I see heroku folder, the file does not exist, so to be honest I am not really sure what does not work.

Comment: Couldn't you dump `$data` within your loop or `$root` outside to see whether data was returned from the database or the file root is set to the value you expect?

Comment: @NicoHaase Yea those all work perfectly alright. Dumping the file path shows the correct path.